# Object level permissions django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model that looks like this..

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    info1 = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    info2 = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    objectAdmin = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

django by default gives access to users to the entire tables if you allow them, but I want the user that is in that row to be the only one to have access to the entry..

so when a particular user logs in, and he goes to the /admin/myapp/samplemodel/1/ ,he should only be able to edit that object if he is the "objectAdmin" of that entry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the queryset in admin based on the user logged in.

```
class SampleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(SampleModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(objectAdmin = request.user)
```

This will ensure that the user has access to objects for which he is assigned as admin.